# Want a NPC to react depending on the time of the day

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Basically, I am trying to create an text-based adventure game where a shopkeeper is added. This shopkeeper has 3 different moods (happy, angry and sad) which depends on the time of the day.

So, from 5 in the morning to 12 noon, the mood of the shopkeeper is happy and it gives out the message like "Hey! Long time no see!", from 12 noon to 10 in the evening his mood is angry and shouts at you and finally from 10 in the evening to 5 in the morning he is scared and says something scary.

I have nearly finished creating everything else but stuck on this shopkeeper. Could someone please help me complete this. For this part I have only managed to code for the time. 
I am not able to write if statement using the time :(

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
    this.dateTimePicker1.Width = 100;
    this.dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
}

private void currentTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
}

private void btnShopkeeper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When constructing logic like this, I think it's important to note what it is you're trying to express.  Are you expressing a behavior/state.. Or are you making a some sort of clock that isn't expressed in numbers?

So I would do something along the lines of defining a behavior..

```
public enum Behavior
{  
   Happy,
   Angry,
   Scary
}

public Behavior GetShopKeeperBehavior()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    if (now.Hour >= 5 && now.Hour < 12) return Behavior.Happy;
    if (now.Hour >=12 && now.Hour < 20) return Behavior.Angry;
    return Behavior.Scary;
}


// usage
Behavior shopKeeperMood = GetShopKeeperBehavior();
if (shopKeeperMood == Behavior.Happy)
{
     // shop keeper says "Long time no see!"
}
```

This will make your calling program code easier to read (rather than have a whole bunch of date time conditions sprinkled throughout your code), and it allows you to add additional behaviors in the future based on some other criteria you may not have thought of yet (which might be based on factors other than time of day).

Comment: Hey guys, I tried both ways... but it only shows 1 message "Im scared" even if i change the time to something else...... Idk what the problem is :(

Comment: @Som what doy ou mean change your time to something else? DateTime.Now goes off your system clock. If you change your clock to say 5 pm, you should get the angry message.

Comment: @Dispersia ya if i change the time to like 8 or 9 in the morning i still get scared message instead of happy... idk what i did wrong :(

Comment: You need to set your break point on "now = DateTime.Now" (or "dt = DateTime.Now" if you're following Dispersia's answer), and see what the value is. My guess is it's actually 8 or 9 pm, as that would fall into the scary range.

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey I used urs but i still get the same message over and over again :(((

Comment: Something else is going on. There isn't anything wrong with the logic.   Is there anything in the code that doesn't make sense to you? The only way to solve this is for you to understand what it's doing and trouble shoot it via the debugger.

Comment: I looked at your code in your answer, and if you want the logic to use the date time picker's date, you will need to set the "now" variable in the GetShopKeeper() method to the value of the date time picker, rather than DateTime.Now.

Comment: ah nvm i figured it out.... thnx for ur help guys... 
i may ask more XD if u guys dont mind that is :)

Comment: No worries. I'll watch for your comments. :)

Comment: I can try. :-) What do you want it to do?

Comment: U know there are NPC in any adventure game who talks to tha player... Similar like that just a NPC who talks to player.... Doesnt have to b complicated just chatting showing 3-4statements one after another

Comment: That's a little vague. :) But I think what you're looking for a dialog tree kind of thing. Probably should ask this as a different question so it doesn't make this SO entry too confusing. Plus it would allow you to see different approaches as far as code goes for those that choose to answer.

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey hmm, i think im gonna change it... ill try to put 1 monster to whom a player can go to and feed him some kind of items which changes the personality of a monster XD... 1 that makes him go laugh like crazy... another makes him adventurous saying like "lets go to some places..." and the last one making him romantic XDXD... could you help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

if (dt.Hour >= 5 && dt.Hour < 12)
{
     //Hey! Long time no see!
}
else if (dt.Hour < 20)
{
     //I'm shouting at you
}
else
{
     //I'm scared :(
}
```